# Traverse through unlimited nested arrays

Tags: php

I am trying to work out a way to get a value "title" from a array that is nested at any unlimited depth in other arrays.

I realise this will need a separate function but for now I am having trouble finding out how to display values down the chain so I can then formulate that into the other function.

The function will be told how many levels to go down, always looking in the "child" element for the next array.

```
$new_map=array();
$new_map[0]["title"]="Level zero";
$new_map[0]["child"]="";


$new_map1=array();
$new_map1[0]["title"]="Level one";
$new_map1[0]["child"]="empty1";

$new_map2=array();
$new_map2[0]["title"]="Level two";
$new_map2[0]["child"]="empty2";

$new_map3=array();
$new_map3[0]["title"]="Level three";
$new_map3[0]["child"]="empty3";


$new_map[0]["child"]=$new_map1;

$new_map1[0]["child"]=$new_map2;

$new_map2[0]["child"]=$new_map3;



foreach($new_map as $key => $val){

foreach($new_map[$key]["child"] as $key2 => $val2){

foreach($new_map[$key]["child"][$key2]["child"] as $key3 => $val3){
echo $new_map[$key]["child"][$key2]["child"][$key3]["title"]."<br/>";
}

}

}
```

Comment: you can think of nested arrays as trees, there is lot of tree traversal algorithms which are based on recursion

Answer (score 0):

You should use Depth First Search to to get a value "title" from a array that is nested at any unlimited depth in other arrays. Instead of taking a new array everytime, take a 3D array

> $new_map[i][0]["child"] where i indicates the ith array.

Then using dfs for $new_map[i][0]["child"], check for the child array $new_map[i + 1][0]["child"] if it contains the value title that you queried.